# Can do multiple statements with stream.mapToObj

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to do multiple statements in `mapToObj` method? . Let say I want to convert a String of characters to a String of binary using the below code:

```
 String str = "hello";
 String bin = str.chars()
                  .mapToObj(x-> Integer.toBinaryString(x))
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

But, I want to handle the leading zeros using something like

```
String.format("%8s", x).replaceAll(" ", "0")
```

So, how to add it in `mapToObj` method. I am very new to Java 8 features. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you want multistatements lambda? ```mapToObj(x -> {...})```

Comment: @Sargey, Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of replacing the space padding you could use `BigInteger` and prepend a '0' during the format step. This works because `BigInteger` is treated as integral.

```
String bin = str.chars()
        .mapToObj(Integer::toBinaryString)
        .map(BigInteger::new)
        .map(x -> String.format("%08d", x))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

#### EDIT

As @Holger suggested there is a more lightweight solution using `long` instead of `BigInteger`, since the binary representation of `Character.MAX_VALUE` does not exceed the limit of `long`.

```
String bin = str.chars()
        .mapToObj(Integer::toBinaryString)
        .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
        .mapToObj(l -> String.format("%08d", l))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: A `long` is already sufficient to hold the maximum transformed `char` value, so you could use `chars() .mapToObj(Integer::toBinaryString) .mapToLong(Long::parseLong) .mapToObj(x -> String.format("%08d", x))`. Or inlined: `.chars() .mapToObj(x -> String.format("%08d", Long.parseLong(Integer.toBinaryString(x)))) .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))` Of course, it would be even easier if the formatting API supported binary representation.

Comment: @Holger You're absolutely right. I haven't thought of that.

Comment: Another nice solution, but can you tell me what is the difference between `.map` and `.mapToObj`. I am confused

Comment: `str.chars()` produces an `IntStream` since this uses an optimized pipeline just by using primitive `int` type, we have to transform the pipeline to a `Stream<Object>` by calling `IntStream::mapToObj`.

Comment: @Alef there are four basic stream types, the generic `Stream<T>` to process objects and `IntStream`, `LongStream`, and `DoubleStream` to handle the primitive types indicated by their names. When you are using `map` on any of them, you’re not changing the basic stream type. When you use `mapToInt`, `mapToLong`, or `mapToDouble`, the mapping operation will change to the indicated primitive type stream, whereas `mapToObj` changes from a primitive type stream to `Stream`. This may affect efficiency as well as the availability of certain type specific convenience methods.

Answer (score 6):

```
.mapToObj(x-> {
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
    s = String.format("%8s", s).replaceAll(" ", "0");
    return s;
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `.map()` function after `.mapToObject()` that will process binary strings, e.g.:

```
String str = "hello";
String bin = str.chars()
              .mapToObj(x-> Integer.toBinaryString(x))
              .map(str -> String.format("%8s", str).replaceAll(" ", "0"))
              .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Is it differ from using multistatements lambda as in Szymon answer?

Comment: Produces same result, but it keeps operations in separation. Useful if you want to apply many different transformations and want to keep your code clean and readable.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. It doesn't even require a lambda expression with multiple statements.

```
String bin = str.chars()
                .mapToObj(x-> String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(x)).replaceAll(" ", "0"))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Too long statement. I meant in two steps. Anyway, many thanks,